# Python3: Minimze subfolders in folder

Tags: python, subdirectory, minimize

How can I minimze levels of subfolders in Python3?
I got main folder

```
/projects/
```

There are many folders, which came from decompressing zip files:

```
/projects/project1/project1/file.txt
/projects/project2/document.txt
```

In the first case, there is one **/project1/** unnecessary subfolder I need to make simple this:

```
/projects/project1/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to simply move the file.txt one level up and remove the inner project1 folder.

You can use os.system() command to run shell commands. Here, you will need 2 shell commands: 1.mv and 2.rm -rf .

```
import os
os.system('mv /projects/project1/project1/file.txt /projects/project1/file.txt')
os.system('rm -rf /projects/project1/project1/')
```

Comment: I need something general, because there is about 1000 subfolders, some of them are ok, some of them not ...

Comment: Can you control the decompression in a way that it does not create a new folder? Maybe, pass some optional arguments to it? If not, consider using a loop for the above code with the 1000 folders, checking every time for the presence of an inner folder which should be fairly simple using string methods or regex.